# Finding a particular number based on existing number in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not able to figure out a solution for my problem..
for example I have a list of codes and rates associated with the codes like,

```
create table a (codes number, rate number);
insert into a values (123, 0.23);
insert into a values (12334, 0.33);
insert into a values (12456, 0.23);
insert into a values (2234, 0.13);
commit;
```

I want only those codes to be selected that has rates for parent codes, for example, here I want 12334 code as we have 123 as its parent code.

Please suggest some pointers if not the exact answer.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define a *parent code*?

Comment: if i have codes 1234 and 123456, then I will consider 1234 as parent code, or as in my example above, 123 is parent code as I have 12334 which will be child code. Basically number having repeat of existing number in the table along with any extra digit. is child and the existing number is parent. thanks!!

Comment: What result would you expect if your relation (table) A(code number, rate number)  also included the rows A(1,.1) and A(1,.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` as follows

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T
WHERE EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE TIN
      WHERE INSTR(T.CODES,TIN.CODES) = 1
      AND T.CODES <> TIN.CODES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from so-called "smart" keys where you have to know the hidden meaning.  Break out the components into their own attributes. That way the data is clear and what you want is easily selected.  Avoid the confusion of "is the code a parent or a child?  Is 12456 a child row where the parent row is missing or is it a parent?

```
create table a (main_code number, sub_code number, rate number);
insert into a values (123,   null, 0.23);
insert into a values (123,   34,   0.33);
insert into a values (12456, null, 0.23);
insert into a values (2234,  null, 0.13);
```

Comment: The abstract advice is good; the implementation is not. The codes seem to form a hierarchy, with more than two levels (potentially); for example, 123 is the parent of 1234, which is the parent of 12345, which is the parent of 123456. How would you model that with your suggestion? The correct way is to show "code" and "parent_code".

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the number to strings for comparison and use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (
    select 1 
    from a a1 
    where a1.codes <> a.codes and a.codes like a1.codes || '%'
)
```

As commented by mathguy, this can be simplified as:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (
    select 1 
    from a a1 
    where a.codes like a1.codes || '_%'
)
```

Metacharacter `'_'` forces `a.codes` to have at least one more character than `a1.codes`, which avoids the need for the inequality check.

Comment: Simpler:  `... where a.codes like a1.codes || '_%'`  That is, by using the underscore metacharacter, require that `a.codes` have at least one more character beyond the initial substring equal to `a1.codes`.

Comment: @mathguy: ah yes that's a good point, I added it to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the result expected

```
  select * from a a1
  where  exists (select 1 from a a2 
  where instr(a1.codes,a2.codes) =1 
  and length(a1.codes) >  length(a2.codes));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to *convert to VARCHAR2* for your numerical model (Though as pointed by others, you could achieve better and stable results with an explicite modeled parent_id column).

To get all rows, that have direct or indirect parent use this query

```
select par.codes parent_codes, cld.codes, cld.rate
from a par 
 join a cld 
 on par.codes < cld.codes and
 par.codes = trunc(cld.codes / power(10,ceil(log(10,cld.CODES)) - ceil(log(10,par.CODES))))


PARENT_CODES      CODES       RATE
------------ ---------- ----------
         123      12334 ,33
```

Note that the `ceil(log(10,cld.CODES))` is the number of the digits in the code. You calculates the difference of the number of digits between the child cade and the parent code and makes a `power` of 10 of it.

This gives e.g. 100 for `12345` and `123`.

The result is used to divide the child code and the whole part of the division (after `trunc`)  is compared with the parent code. If they are eqaul  the child code has a parent.

*You may also consider this calculation as a feasibility study of your model*